# Route in React Js

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I Have two components one is Main.js and Search.js I want to link button in Main.js to navigate to Search.js, but I'm not sure how to do it.

```
import React from "react";
import classes from "./Main.module.css";
import Aux from "../../hoc/Aux";
import logo from "../../containers/img/Logo.png";
import Search from "../Search/Search";
import { Route } from "react-router-dom";
const Main = () => {
  return (
    <Aux>
      {/* Section starts */}
      <section className={classes.Showcase}>
        {/* Section Left */}
        <div className={classes.ShowcaseLeft}>
          <div className={classes.ShowcaseLeftTop}></div>
          <div className={classes.ShowcaseLeftBottom}></div>
        </div>
        {/* Section Right */}
        <div className={classes.ShowcaseRight}>
          <div className={classes.ShowcaseRightTop}></div>
          <div className={classes.ShowcaseRightRest}>
            <img src={logo} alt="Logo" />
            <p>
              Provide weather, water, and climate data, forecasts and warnings
              for the protection of life and property and enhancement of the
              national economy.
            </p>
            <Route path="/auth" component={Search} />
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
    </Aux>
  );
};
export default Main;
```

Comment: You want `<Link>` not `<Route>`

Comment: Error: Invariant failed: You should not use <Link> outside a <Router>

Comment: Ok so make a router

Comment: Please share your routing code/logic, and as @mousetail points out, you'll need a `Link` to the path you want to navigate to.

Comment: I created The search component    ---> import Search from "../Search/Search";
I created the Link ---> import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
Trying to connect to it ---->             <Link path="/Search" component={Search} />

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options: either use react-router-dom `useHistory` hook, or the Link component. Here are the two ways:

```
// useHistory
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

function Main() {
  let history = useHistory();
  return (
    <button type="button" onClick={()=> history.push("/search")}>
      search
    </button>
  );
}

// Link
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

function Main() {
  let history = useHistory();
  return (
  <Link to="/search">
    <button type="button">
      search
    </button>
  </Link>
  );
}
```

A last piece of advice: I would suggest to add all your paths in a single file, so you can never make any typo. In the end, the ideal would be to write something like: `<Link to={path.search}>`

Comment: Im getting somewhere It tells me history is undefined

Comment: I think it is not reading the component Search but it almost works

Comment: Have you correctly imported it? https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/usehistory you need to import it, and then to instantiate it with `const history = useHistory()`; . Just a note: by using useHistory, you don't provide your user with the url preview. To do it, you need to use Link. useHistory is mostly used inside functions to redirect the user once an action is done.

Comment: yes I have done it but the problem I think is in the component /Search in the button